# How does Lurianic Kabbalah treat Da'at?

Tags: words, mysticism-kabbalah

[Da'at](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da%27at) is difficult to interpret. I have found [this](http://www.inner.org/sefirot/sefdaat.htm) and [this](http://cdcruz.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/daat-knowledge-and-union/), but I am looking for the Lurianic interpretation specifically.

Please note that I cannot read Hebrew.

Comment: What about it specifically?

Comment: I have heard it said that Da'at fell through the Tree. I would like to know if this is agreed upon in Lurianic Kabbalah, and how it is described. I have a lot of questions about Da'at and the Negative Veils, but that is the most relevant.

Comment: Wait you can't read Hebrew and you're asking questions about Kabbala?

Comment: @HachamGabriel Yes. It doesn't come up as often as you'd expect.